# Programmatically set margins in a MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have some views that need some margins set programmatically (from an applyWindowInsets listener), but the views seem to be ignoring any margins I set with my code, even though I am not animating the margins.

I'm able to set padding just fine, but I cannot accomplish what I need using only padding.

The issue seems to be related to MotionLayout since it works fine if it is a ConstraintLayout.

I've been using this util method.

```
public static void addTopMargin(View v, int margin) {
    ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += margin;
}
```

Comment: I have been using a workaround that doesn't work in all cases, but enough that I was able to accomplish what I needed. If you put the view you want to control in a LinearLayout, you can control whatever properties you need on the child object, and the motion layout will control all the properties on the LinearLayout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you're having is that `MotionLayout` derives its margins from the assigned `ConstraintSets`, so changing the base margin isn't actually doing anything. To get this to work, you need to target one or both of the `ConstraintSets` that define the `MotionScene`:

```
val motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motionLayoutId)
motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.startingConstraintSet)?
    .setMargin(targetView.id, anchorId, value)
```

You could also do this for more than one view with a `let`:

```
val motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motionLayoutId)
motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.startingConstraintSet)?.let {
    setMargin(firstView.id, anchorId, value)
    setMargin(secondView.id, anchorId, value)
}
```

For the top margin, use `ConstraintSet.TOP`, etc.

Remember that if you're not wanting to animate that margin, you'll have to assign to both the start and end `ConstraintSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a simple note to UnOrthodox solution that in case of you don't need to animate that margin you will need to keep the base margin with adding the ConstraintSets margin:

```
public static void addTopMargin(View v, int margin) {
    ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += margin;
    MotionLayout root = findViewById(R.id.motion_layout);
    root.getConstraintSet(R.id.start).setMargin(firstView.id, anchorId, margin);
    root.getConstraintSet(R.id.end).setMargin(firstView.id, anchorId, margin);
}
```